# How to solve $y''+\frac{y'}{x}+cy=0$？

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this ode?

$$y''+\dfrac{y'}{x}+cy=0.$$

$c$ is a real number. I can rewrite it to $(xy')'+cxy=0$ but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: It's Bessel's equation ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is cylindrical  Bessel equation whose solution is 
$$y(x)=A J_{0}(x \sqrt{c})+ BY_{0} (x \sqrt{c}).$$
You may see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Answer (score 0):

$y′′ + y'/x + cy = 0$

$x^2 y′′ + xy' + cx^2 y = 0$

$x^2 y′′ + xy' + ((\sqrt c)^2x^2 y = 0$
You can see that the equation above is similar to the following equation:

$x^2 y"+(2k +1)xy'−(α^2 x^2r + β^2)y = 0$, with k, \alpha, r, \betha are constants.

That is the equation transformed into the Bessel equation.
The general solution is [image: the picture].

Comment: How does that help?